# How to properly use the write() function for sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, error-handling

I'm using the [write()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/write.html) function to write to a socket in C. I am not a C expert, and sometimes I know this function can fail, in those cases it can return some kind of SIGPIPE.

Here's the simple piece of code I'm using now:

```
if(write(sockfd, sendline, sizeof(sendline)) < sizeof(sendline))
    {
        printf("Failed to write string %s to socket" , sendline);
        return NULL;
    }
```

My question is, how can I properly manage those kind of errors (SIGPIPE, etc) when using this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as "how to handle errors", you need to check for the return value of `write()` being `-1`, and then if you want to distinguish between error conditions look at the value of `errno`.

In the specific case of `SIGPIPE`, this is delivered to a process if an attempt is make to write to a socket whose reading end is closed. By default, the delivery of `SIGPIPE` will cause the process to terminate. If you do not want this behaviour, then you will need to explicitly ignore `SIGPIPE` (`signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`), and then the `write()` call will return `-1` and `errno` will equal `EPIPE`.